# Endpoint message notification logger in mule does not get invoked

Tags: mule

I want to log the payloads (centralized logging) being sent out from my HTTP endpoints (requester) for which I figured it is best to use the `EndpointMessageNotificationListener`

The server starts up correctly but my notification logger does not get called. I expect the onNotification method to be invoked each time a request is sent out from the HTTP Requester.

Now I have configured the spring bean.

```
<spring:bean name="endpointNotificationLogger" class="EndpointAuditor" />
```

My Java class is as below

```
public class EndpointAuditor implements EndpointMessageNotificationListener<EndpointMessageNotification> {

  public EndpointAuditor(){
    System.out.println("The EndpointAuditor has been instantiated");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNotification(EndpointMessageNotification notification) {
    try {
      System.out.println("This comes from the endpoint " + notification.getSource().getPayloadAsString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

and my notification configuration as below

```
<notifications>
        <notification event="ENDPOINT-MESSAGE" />
        <notification-listener ref="endpointNotificationLogger" />
    </notifications>
```

I have picked up all this from [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications#MuleServerNotifications-NotificationInterfaces).

Any ideas why Mule is not happy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one turned out to be a tricky one. I was using Mule 3.6.1 EE with the new HTTP Connector and this feature is not implemented with the HTTP Connector in this particular Mule version.

So basically I was doing all the right things and Mule just did'nt have the feature.

But they have implemented it with Mule 3.6.3 EE and Mule 3.7.X. This [commit](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/commit/825db53585009fa5c26ed53739f6643a9c6b3180) shows how the code written for it.